# Converting MDB File With Unicode Characters

Tags: gdal, c#, ogr, personal-geodatabase, unicode

I'm using C# wrapper of GDAL and I'm having a problem converting MDB file that contains unicode characters.

Lets take for example conversion to KML file,
non-English characters are replaced by '?'

How do I solve it?